# Django QuerySets: Get unique/first element from ForeignKey field

Tags: mysql, django, orm, django-queryset

I've following models:

```
class SchoolClass(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    max_students = models.IntegerField(default=10)
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Session(models.Model):
    school_class = models.ForeignKey(SchoolClass, related_name="sessions")
    start_date = models.DateField()
    enrolled_students = models.IntegerField()
```

A SchoolClass can have multiple Sessions (e.g. "Maths for Dummies" on Monday, Tuesday and Friday = 3 Sessions).

On my Index page (ListView), I'd like to show all upcoming classes (which have at least one session) only once, since classes which have a lot of sessions would make the overview messy.

How can I create a list of Session-Objects (I can get the relevant course info via session.school_class), which comply with following requirements:

- `start_date__gte=datetime.now().date()`
- `school_class.is_published=True`
- it's the first elelement of SchoolClass (`oder_by('start_date')[0]`)

Thanks!

PS: I'm running MySQL as DB, so distinct('field') won't work..

---

**Edit:**

Below is my current solution, which works, but is not very clean (redundant hits on the DB)

```
def get_sessions_mixin(filter_args):
    session_qs = []
    qs = SchoolClass.objects.filter(**filter_args)
    for schoolclass in qs:
        session_qs.append(schoolclass.get_first_session())

    #session_qs = Session.objects.filter(course_meta__is_deleted=False, date_from__gte=datetime.now().date()).\
    #    annotate(Max('date_from'))
    #session_qs = qs.order_by('get_first_session__date_from')

    return session_qs
```

and inside models.py

```
class Sessions(models.Model):
    # ...
    def get_first_session(self):
        if self.is_published:
            tmp_sessions = self.sessions.filter(date_from__gte=datetime.now().date())
            if tmp_sessions:
            return tmp_sessions.order_by('date_from')[0]
    return None
```

Comment: Can you please explain the third bullet point more clearly..

Comment: Sure. If a SchoolClass object is related to e.g. 3 Session objects, I just want the first (earliest) Session object in the QuerySet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of a way to do what you want in a single Django ORM query. What I would probably do is, first, get all of the relevant `Session` objects:

```
sessions = Session.objects.filter(school_class__is_published=True,
                                  start_date__gte=datetime.now().date())
                          .select_related('school_class')
                          .order_by('start_date')
```

You now have everything you need, including the related `SchoolClass` data, from a single query. You just have to do some work in Python to filter the data. There are many ways you could do that, here's a simple one:

```
first_sessions = collections.OrderedDict()
for session in sessions:
    if session.school_class.pk not in first_sessions:
        first_sessions[session.school_class.pk] = session
```

And now `first_sessions.values()` has what you want. You could wrap this up in a method on a custom `Manager`.

It's hard to make guesses about performance when databases are involved (especially without knowing how many `Sessions` there are for a typical `SchoolClass`), but I suspect this single-query approach will be faster and simpler than your current solution, which hits the database many times.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've decided to add a field (first_session) to the SchoolClass model and update it (via signals) every time a Session is changed. Sometimes denormalization is a fine thing :) I will mark your answer as accepted since it's the closest correct answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this kind of query may work:

```
SchoolClass.objects.filter(sessions__start_date__gte=datetime.now().date(), is_published=True)\
    .annotate(session_count=Count('sessions'))\
    .filter(session_count__gte=1)
```

But I'm not sure about what the third bullet point means.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This might work, but I'm trying to get a QuerySet of Session objects (the first/earliest one of each SchoolClass object)..

Comment: [`.earliest('sessions_start_date')`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#earliest)